# C++: Get MacOS version

Tags: c++, macos

I need to find a way to find the OS version of a MacOS system, preferably without external libraries.
How would that be possible?

I don't have a MacOS machine to be able to test the code.

Compiler: g++

Comment: My mistake... Fixed that.

Comment: If you don't have a Mac to test on, why do you need the version? There will be no guarantee your software will even compile when on a Mac

Comment: I am creating a piece of software featuring some helpful functions (this one is supposed to work like Python's platform.release function).

Comment: You can read try reading [`/usr/bin/sw_vers`](https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch/blob/2df24a89b0692d82c3c4a7cb0550a0087a9a0905/screenfetch-dev#L1053) like screenFetch does.

Comment: Interesting. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I know you said you'd prefer no external libraries, but if you went down that path one option is the class [Poco::Environment](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Environment.html) (Foundation/Core), which has a method `osVersion`.

Comment: Does that function also work for Windows/Linux? If so, I will definitely use it!

Comment: @Bonfire Poco? Yes, it's cross-platform. I used it ages ago so I don't remember much, but you should be able to link only the foundation library for that (which can be built static or dynamic), not the whole thing.

Comment: Is there a way to find the source code for the function directly? i.e from https://github.com/waTeim/poco/

Comment: @Bonfire Sure, the class source is [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.10.0-release/Foundation/src/Environment.cpp), it has multiple implementation files depending on the operative system, for macOS it would be [`Environment_UNIX`](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/poco-1.10.0-release/Foundation/src/Environment_UNIX.cpp). The `osVersion` implementation simply uses [`uname`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html).

Comment: Alright. I will try re-implementing the Poco source code and change it a bit for my needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206809/discussion-between-bonfire-and-jdehesa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to do:

```cpp
#include <sys/utsname.h>

void main() {
    struct utsname uts;
    uname(&uts);
    return uts.release;
}
```

Comment: This gives the Darwin kernel version but not the macOS version :(